# How to run a query to get results of last 12 months ( BigQuery)

Tags: sql, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I want to get records for last 12 months for a particular ID in Big Query table. I have extracted month and year as separate columns from the original timestamp column. I tried using date_add() and date_diff() but i am getting some errors. My Dataset is like:

```
Month Year MonthName    ID
8     2018   August      1
9     2018   September   2
9     2017   September   3
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> I have extracted month and year as separate columns from the original timestamp column

I recommend doing 12 months filtering based on your original timestamp column.
Assuming it is named `ts` - below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
WHERE DATE(ts) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

for example

```
#standardSQL
SELECT ts, id
FROM `project.dataset.table`
WHERE id = 1
AND DATE(ts) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

One method is to convert the year/month into months since some date.  Then do the same with the current date:

```
where year * 12 + month >= extract(year from current_date) * 12 + extract(month from current_date) - 12
```

This assumes you have no future data.  The same idea holds for future dates (using < rather than >=).

Answer (score 0):

`timestamp` is assumed as standard timestamp naming for your BQ table as time identifier field. So you can filter like below to get last 12 month data only:

```
WHERE DATE(TIMESTAMP_MILLIS(timestamp)) BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 12 MONTH) and CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the last 12 full-months:

```
SELECT
  DATE_SUB((DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month)), INTERVAL 1 month),
  DATE_SUB((DATE_TRUNC(CURRENT_DATE(), month)), INTERVAL 13 month)
```